# extract certain sheet from huge excel files into new excel file using matlab

Tags: matlab, xls

is that possible to extract out all the data in second sheet from each of the excel file into new excel file? mean that i have a huge excel files in a folder, i would like to extract out all the second sheet from each of the excel file into new excel file. The sheet name is not the same.

```
fns = dir('*.xls');
for i = 1:length(fns)
s=xlsread('fns(i).name', 2); %read second sheet for each .xls file
xlswrite('newfile.xls'); %write the second sheet to newfile.xls
end
```

I have problem with the code i wrote above. anyone can help?

Comment: What did you try so far? According to the [documentation of `xlsread`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/xlsread.html), it can deal with individual sheets identified by an integer number. So does `xlswrite`. Do you need help in applying them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following structure of files:

```
in\
|__ Book1.xls
|__ Book2.xls
```

Here is an example where we read the second sheet from each XLS file in the directory `in`, and write them all out as sheets to a new file `out.xls` in the current folder:

```
dirName = 'c:\path\to\in';
files = dir( fullfile(dirName,'*.xls') );
files = {files.name}';                    %'

SHEET_NUM = 2;
for i=1:numel(files)
    [~,~,rawData] = xlsread(fullfile(dirName,files{i}), SHEET_NUM);
    xlswrite('out.xls', rawData, i);
end
```